# Ubuntu Desktop boots, but Ubuntu Server doesn't

Tags: boot, 18.04, server

Installer version is `ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` on USB made with Rufus, computer is Thinkpad X220

Steps to reproduce: Unplug network cable and install with default settings ("entire disk") + SSH. Installation goes as normal (cross-referenced the log output with a VM that works). Accept final prompt to restart, remove USB... and the laptop skips to the PXE boot. With manual boot device selection, it goes black for a second and then comes back to boot device selection screen.

But Ubuntu Desktop works. Debian also works.

What's going on?

Comment: You mention is works in a VM, was it a VM on identical hardware? or else you may not have used the same kernel modules (drivers) etc. and thus your 'okay' logic is flawed.  If not an flawed ISO or write ot media, I'd suspect BIOS/setting config next.  Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: The 'live' server has less hardware kernel modules available than the regular installer (it's mostly intended for very simple installs & using it's 'live' session unavailable on the main server ISO) so this maybe an issue too.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so how do I fill in the missing hardware kernel modules? I did try installing it *with* internet so it would've hopefully downloaded any missing modules, but still it didn't boot.

Answer (score 0):

X220 should be supported I'd imagine, and I've typically seen the server build to install easier than the desktop so surprised it's causing issues. A couple of things to check is whether the BIOS is set to legacy or UEFI (I believe both should be ok, but on the older hardware might be better to use the legacy option - press F2 or Enter on a Thinkpad I believe). Also always good to just try re-flashing the boot media. Since it's showing the whole install process likely not the issue, but recreating the USB disk is always a good sanity check (I think Ember is getting popular or you can just run dd if= of=/dev/ bs=64k).